# Internet works only in VM but not on my Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine

I installed VMware Workstation, and I installed a guest machine which is kali linux. At first, everything was working normally. Until I found later that when I connect to a WI-fi or an Ethernet cable, I get access to Internet only in my Virtual machine not on my windows 10.

Comment: Open `ncpa.cpl` control panel, double click on the main interface, check the IPv4 and IPv6 to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please open CMD on your Windows 10, type “***ipconfig /all***”, make sure that your TCP/IP Parameters(such as IP address, gateway, DNS server) are correctly configured, or, you can try to assign appropriate statics IP address and check the result.

Suggestions mentioned in “**Fix network connection issues in Windows 10**” can be considered as reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/10741/windows-10-fix-network-connection-issues

Best Regards,
Eve Wang